# Conditional styles, hover and ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs

I have an anchor within a `<div>`, the anchor uses conditional styling for it's background and this seems make it so that the `a:hover` style gets discarded. Actually it doesn't matter if I have conditional or just a fixed color, if I remove the background-style from `component.js` the hover-effect from `style.css` kicks in.

My question is how do I achieve the hover effect while still having a conditional background-color?

component.js:

```
<div>
  <a href="#"
     style={{
       background: (day === 2) && "#f1f1f1"
     }} />
</div>
```

style.css:

```
div a {
  display: block;
}
div a:hover {
  background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to use `!important` to force the `:hover` behaviour even when inline styles as you have are applied, like so:

```
div a:hover {
  background: blue !important;
}
```

If dynamic inline styling is not required (ie you don't need a dynamic background color), then you'll typically want to avoid the use of `!important` in favour of `class` based styling:

**JSX**

```
<div>
  <a href="#" className={ (day === 2) && "dayTwoClass" } />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div a {
  display: block;
}

// Increased specificity of div to a causes blue background on hover
div a:hover {
  background: blue;
}

// Lesser specificity causes f1f1f1 background when not hovered
.dayTwoClass {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}
```

Comment: Wait, I'm sure I tried that but I couldn't have because it works.. Thanks! :D

Comment: i have to downvote this. Stay away from using tags as selectors as well as `!important`. It decreases the maintainability of your stylesheets and you'll get into a mess real fast.

Comment: @JoshKelly fair enough - the answer does recommend against the use of `!important` in favour of the class based alternative :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a great use case for CSS stylesheet vs inline styles which will override due to [css specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Pop a class on it and do something like.

```
.conditional {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.conditional:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Yes I get it, that is better than `!important`. I ended up going for `className= {(day===2) && "activeDay"}` and moving the styles to the external stylesheet.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add, take a look at styled components https://www.styled-components.com/  . Its a matter of preference but using the style object can be a bit limiting and difficult to read (IMHO), some would say styled components is hard to read - your choice
There's lots more to styled components so definitely worth taking a look.
your use case would be something like below (or you could have your styled component in a different module)

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const Link = styled.a`
  display: block;

  & :hover {
    background: ${props => props.dayValue === 2 ? white : blue};
  }
`

render(){
  return (<div> <Link href='' dayValue={this.props.dayValue}/></div>)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your tip, I will definitely consider this. It can become quite messy with the inline styling.